# CakePHP find() on HABTM association table with missing model

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-model

I'm building an e-commerce site using CakePHP 2.3.x that has a `Product` model associated with an `Order` model in a HABTM relationship and I'm using `orders_products` as my join table. I have all of the associations working correctly and doing a `find()` on the `Order` model brings up all the associated products. My problem is that I'm trying to make the association still happen if the `Product` can't be found.

I'm saving relevant information in the association table but I can't find a way to make the association without the `Product` model being found. I have info such as the item's name, price at time of sale, etc. stored in the association so the controller and view can compensate for an item that may have been deleted, changed ID somehow, or whatever else could happen.

I've searched all over but can't seem to find a better solution than manually building a query for the join table. Is there a proper Cake way of doing this, or should I use a separate model such as `OrderProduct`?

Here's the `Order` model:

```
class Order extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Order';
    public $belongsTo = array('User');
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Product' => array(
            'className' => 'Product',
            'joinTable' => 'orders_products',
            'foreignKey' => 'order_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'product_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting'
        )
    );
}
```

And here's the `Product` model:

```
class Product extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Product';
    public $belongsTo = array('Category', 'Brand');
    public $hasMany = array('ProductPhoto');
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Order' => array(
            'className' => 'Order',
            'joinTable' => 'orders_products',
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'order_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting'
        )
    );
```

TLDR Version: When I do `$this->Order->find('first', $options)` I get all the products in the returned `Order` data, but only if there is a match on the join table (`orders_products`) to the `Product` model. I'm trying to make the join table result, `$data['Order']['OrderProduct']`, in the returned data regardless if the `Product` can be found in the database.

Comment: Show your code, mostly your associations.

Comment: If it helps, I'm trying to do this automatically and without manually creating a query. Is there a model function for querying the join table?